# Flask testing, post file and nested dictionaries

Tags: python, flask, multipartform-data

I have created a Flask app and wanted to test it. In a single endpoint, I would like to post a multipart request, which includes a file and a complex JSON object. I thought at first of using werkzeug EnvironBuilder for this task, as it seems to provide a quite automated approach, handling content types, etc. My snippet of code for preparing the request is the following:

```
# client is an instance of FlaskClient produced using a pytest fixture and the method test client

def _post(endpoint, file_path=None, serialized_message=None):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fin:
                fil = io.BytesIO(fin.read())
        file_name = file_path.split(os.sep)[-1]
        builder = EnvironBuilder(path='/' + endpoint,
                                 method='POST',
                                  data=json.loads(
                                      serialized_message),
                                content_type="application/json")
        builder.files[file_name] = fil
        result = client.open(builder, buffered=True)
        return result
```

This failed with the following error:

```
 def _add_file_from_data(self, key, value):
        """Called in the EnvironBuilder to add files from the data dict."""
        if isinstance(value, tuple):
            self.files.add_file(key, *value)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            from warnings import warn
            warn(DeprecationWarning('it\'s no longer possible to pass dicts '
                                    'as `data`.  Use tuples or FileStorage '
                                    'objects instead'), stacklevel=2)
            value = dict(value)
            mimetype = value.pop('mimetype', None)
            if mimetype is not None:
                value['content_type'] = mimetype
>           self.files.add_file(key, **value)
E           TypeError: add_file() got an unexpected keyword argument 'globalServiceOptionId'
```

With the `globalServiceOptionId` being a key of a nested dictionary in the dictionary I am posting. I have some thoughts over bypassing this problem, with converting to string jsons the inner dictionaries, but I would like something more concrete as an answer, as I do not want the representation of the request to be changed inside and outside of testing. Thank you.

### Update 1

The form of the passwed dictionary doesn't really matter, as long as it has nested dictionaries inside it. This json is given in this example:

```
{
    "attachments": [],
    "Ids": [],
    "globalServiceOptions": [{
      "globalServiceOptionId": {
        "id": 2,
        "agentServiceId": {
          "id": 2
        },
        "serviceOptionName": "Time",
        "value": "T_last",
        "required": false,
        "defaultValue": "T_last",
        "description": "UTC Timestamp",
        "serviceOptionType": "TIME"
      },
      "name": "Time",
      "value": null
    }]
  }
```

### Update 2

I tested another snippet:

```
    def _post(endpoint, file_path=None, serialized_message=None):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fin:
                fil = io.BytesIO(fin.read())
        files = {
         'file': (file_path, fil, 'application/octet-stream')
        }
        for key, item in json.loads(serialized_message).items():
            files[key] = (None, json.dumps(item), 'application/json')

        builder = EnvironBuilder(path='/' + endpoint,
                                 method='POST', data=files,
                                 )
        result = client.open(builder, buffered=True)
        return result
```

Although this runs without errors, Flask recognizes (as expected) the incoming jsons as files, which again requires different handling during testing and normal running.

Comment: What's the type of `self.files`? Seems like the `add_file` method off of that object can't handle a dictionary with key `'globalServiceOptionId'`, according to the error.

Comment: Can you post your `serialized_message`? You're passing that as data to `EnvironBuilder` and it tries to extract files data from it at which point it fails.

Comment: Added an example or the `serialized_message`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue, and what ended up working for me was changing the data approach to exclude nested dicts.  Taking your sample JSON, doing the following should allow it to clear the `EnvironBuilder`:

```
data_json = {
    "attachments": [],
    "Ids": [],
    "globalServiceOptions": [json.dumps({  # Dump all nested JSON to a string representation
            "globalServiceOptionId": {
                "id": 2,
                "agentServiceId": {
                    "id": 2
                },
                "serviceOptionName": "Time",
                "value": "T_last",
                "required": false,
                "defaultValue": "T_last",
                "description": "UTC Timestamp",
                "serviceOptionType": "TIME"
            },
            "name": "Time",
            "value": null
        })
    ]
}
builder = EnvironBuilder(path='/' + endpoint,
                             method='POST',
                              data=data_json,
                            content_type="application/json")
```

Taking the approach above still allowed the nested dict/JSON to be passed appropriately while clearing the werkzeug limitation.